# How to use an array element as an index of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've two arrays in `javascript` code. I want to use element of the array `x`  as index for the array `y`.

You can see I've numbers in the array `x`, so is there any possible and easy way I can do it.

```
<script>
    var x = [1,2,3,4,6]
    var y = ["kin","kim","jong","ving","gon","von","rick"]
</script>
```

like

```
 y+x[4]  //(not a code just for idea)
```

must print **"rick"**.

I tried

```
 y+x[4] //I know that's stupid
```

but its not working. Please provide answer in javascript.

Comment: I think you should use `y[x[4]]`

Comment: Why don't you use a Hash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read about [MDN - Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) more.

```
var x = [1,2,3,4,6]
var y = ["kin","kim","jong","ving","gon","von","rick"]
var index = x[4]; //6
console.log(y[index]); // at index 6, value is "rick"
```

Or

```
y[x[4]] // "rick"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass `x[4]` as the index to `y`
 i.e `y[x[4]]`, which outputs "rick."

Answer (score 0):

I would use another type of data structure, hashes which stores key value pairs and is appropriate for your use:

```
var x = { 0: "Kin",
          1: "kim",
          2: "jong",
          3: "vin",
          4: "gon",
          5: "von",
          6: "rich" }
```

Then to access the data you can do something like this:

```
x[1] // "kim"
```

or

```
x[4] // "gon"
```

Comment: there is no '0' and five in '5' in aaray x in my question, what if ill change the values of x.